# Cancel Rollback and accept data loss

Tags: sql-server-2012, rollback

I have a SQL instance (2012 Standard Edition) which consumes all CPU resources because of a rollback-process. The instance has been restarted, so the database is currently `In Recovery`. I cannot see any SPID in Status ROLLBACK with `sp_who2` or `sp_whoisactive`.

The data within that database is not important, but it's currently wasting all my CPU and slowing down the application.

Is there any chance of cancelling the rollback. I am absolutely willing to completely lose the affected database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the error logs, It should tell you the percentage the recovery process is on.

This would give an idea of how long the recovery would take to complete.